# jQTouch _webapp link

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqtouch

I have one main page and other sources on other pages. Since I can't use ajax loading because of the server limitation, I have to use target="_webapp" attribute to load on new page

```
<div id="home">
<a href="/the-external.page.html" target="_webapp">Link to external page</a>

... content ...
</div>
```

Since normal back button (        a href="#") doesn't work with external page, I'm using javascript:history.go(-1)

```
<div id="the-external-page">
<div class="toolbar">
<h1>The External Page</h1>
<a class="back" href="javascript:history.go(-1)">Back</a>
</div>
<ul>
<li><a href="#page1">Internal page</a></li>
<li><a href="#page2">Internal page</a></li>
</ul>

... content ...
</div>
<div id="page1">
<div class="toolbar">
<h1>Page 1</h1>
<a class="back" href="#">Back</a>
</div>
.. content...
</div>
<div id="page2">
<div class="toolbar">
<h1>Page 2</h1>
<a class="back" href="#">Back</a>
</div>
.. content...
</div>
```

It works if user navigate #home -> #the-external-page -> #home

but since the other pages have multiple link within it when user visit #page1, #page2 all the history stack and the back button doesn't work until pressed multiple time.

I can't put absolute link in the back button either because the list of original pages are dynamically generated.

Is there way to go back to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Did not test with your code, but I suspect .goBack() in the jQtouch object may be what you're looking for: https://code.google.com/p/jqtouch/wiki/PublicObject

Relevant section:

> `goBack( to:object )`
>
> Forces jQTouch to go back to a certain page in the history. You can pass a specific page ID, a number of pages to go back, or nothing to go back one page. If the specified page can not be found, jQTouch will go back one page by default.